# How do I parse this local JSON file?

Tags: ios, swift

```
"documenttypes": [{
        "documentname": "DNC Format",
        "mandatory": "0",
        "limitnumber": "2",
        "supportingfiles": {
            "document": [{
                "type": "DNC Format",
                "displayname": "DNC_Format"
            }]
        }
    },

    {
        "documentname": "Joint Life Addendum",
        "mandatory": "0",
        "limitnumber": "3",
        "supportingfiles": {
            "document": [{
                "type": "Joint Life Addendum",
                "displayname": "Joint_Life_Addendum"
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "documentname": "Age proof of Child",
        "mandatory": "0",
        "limitnumber": "3",
        "supportingfiles": {
            "document": [{
                "type": "Age proof of Child",
                "displayname": "Age_proof_of_Child"
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "documentname": "Permanent Address Proof of Proposer",
        "mandatory": "0",
        "limitnumber": "4",
        "supportingfiles": {
            "document": [{
                "type": "AADHAR Card",
                "displayname": "AADHAR_Card"
            },
            {
                "type": "Aadhar Card letter",
                "displayname": "Aadhar_Card_letter"
            },
            {
                "type": "KMBL KYC ",
                "displayname": "KMBL_KYC "
            },
            {
                "type": "Driving License",
                "displayname": "Driving_License"
            }
            ]
        }
    }]
```

I am fetching the type key into typeArray, but I need to fetch as array of arrays:

```
if let personArray = jsonResult.value(forKey: "documenttypes") as? NSArray {
    for (_, element) in personArray.enumerated() {
    if let element = element as? NSDictionary {
        let id = element.value(forKey: "documentname") as! String
        self.documentnameArr.append(id)

        let files = element.value(forKey: "supportingfiles") as! NSDictionary

        if let personArray = files.value(forKey: "document") as? NSArray {
            for (_, element) in personArray.enumerated() {
                if let element = element as? NSDictionary {

                    if let myArr = element.value(forKey: "type"){

                        self.typeArr.append(myArr as! String)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am fetching all the type key values in `typeArr` but I need the values like array of arrays:

[["DNC FORMAT"],["Joint Life Addendum"],[Age proof of Child],[AADHAR Card,Aadhar Card letter,KMBL KYC ,Driving License]]

Comment: Use `Codable` instead and use native swift classes like Array and Dictionary instead of NS classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my code:

```
var documentnameArr: [String] = []
var typeArr:[[String]] = []
if let personArray = jsonResult["documenttypes"] as NSArray? {
    for (_, element) in personArray.enumerated() {
    if let element = element as? NSDictionary {
        let id = element.value(forKey: "documentname") as! String
        documentnameArr.append(id)
        let files = element.value(forKey: "supportingfiles") as! NSDictionary
        if let personArray = files.value(forKey: "document") as? NSArray {
            var arrayInDocument: [String] = []
            for (_, element) in personArray.enumerated() {
                if let element = element as? NSDictionary {
                    if let myArr = element.value(forKey: "type"){
                        arrayInDocument.append(myArr as! String)
                    }
                }
            }
            typeArr.append(arrayInDocument)
        }
    }
    }
}
print(documentnameArr)
print(typeArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON parsing will be more straightforward if you use swift `Codable`. 
You never need to iterate through JSON keys in this way, You only just need to parse it to appropriate struct and classes based on your need.

For example in your case, you need to create three structs for your JSON types: `documenttypes`, `supportingfiles` and `document`.

In case you need these types to be only decoded you can just conform to `Decodable`.

You can read more about pasign JSON using `Codable` in this article provided by [John Sundel](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/codable/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "SwiftyJSON" pod from Cocoapods, highly recommended.